# Are the iPad 2 30-pin cable and the iPod touch cable different?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipad, charger

They look the same and get mixed up. My iPad 2 can't charge with the iPod's cable but vice-versa works.

Might this iPad question apply?: [Using an iPod charging cable to charge an iPad](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2128/using-an-ipod-charging-cable-to-charge-an-ipad)

Can this behavior be because the iPad 2 30-pin cable and the iPod touch cable are somehow made differently?

Comment: The question you linked to could very well be relevant, as the cables should be identical, but the chargers may well not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USB-to-30-pin-dock cables are electrically identical. All of them can carry enough charging current for both devices. The same is not true for the power sources as the iPad gets a 10W supply and the rest 5W.

What power source are you using with the cables? iPads need more power than most USB ports offer to charge with the screen on.

Comment: And even with the screen off the iPad takes a really long time to charge with a standard iPod or iPhone USB charger.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the edit. That's exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Interestingly, you can charge off the USB ports on a Macbook Pro pretty fast. I suspect that the MacBook Pro can supply a lot more voltage for just this reason. At least you can charge, though. The first generation iPads simply would not charge on non-iPad chargers.

Comment: @vy32 Yes, most recent Macs will happily charge an iPad. And first-gen iPads could charge on less-than-10-watt chargers, but you had to turn them off first.

Comment: @CajunLuke, ah, but who turned off their iPads?  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @vy32 People with underpowered chargers and this one person I saw on the subway once.

Comment: does the ipod charge faster on the ipad wall charger then?

Comment: @iceman Probably not. The iPod'll only pull as much current as it actually needs.

Answer (score 1):

The standard iPad/iPhone/iPod Touch cables are identical and interchangeable. As the [Apple store item](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MA591G/B/apple-dock-connector-to-usb-cable) notes:

> This USB 2.0 cable connects your **iPhone, iPad or iPod** — directly
>   or through a Dock — to your computer's USB port for efficient syncing
>   and charging or to the Apple USB Power Adapter for convenient charging
>   from a wall outlet.

However, the chargers are different - as commenter @Mark noted, it takes a long time to charge an iPad with an iPod charger.

iPhone/iPod Touch charger specs (from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00510E79Y)):

> Input:110-240V 50/60Hz 1.0A, Output:**5V==1A**

iPad charger specs (from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004NUS72G)):

> Input: 100-240V 0.45A 50/60Hz, Output : **5.1V 2.1A 10W**

The iPad charger can output twice the wattage and current of the iPod charger, so your iPad will charge a lot more slowly if you use your iPod charger (at about a quarter of the speed using the iPad charger). If your iPad is on, it may not even charge because it's power usage is higher than the iPod charger's capacity to charge, as noted in [Adam's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45192/10639) in the question you've quoted.